# Generate h1 et h2 inside link with theme function

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to modify a module.

I have two variables: let say **$date = "mydate"** and **$title = "mytitle"**

I have for the moment a theming function that creates a link by doing something like this:

```
$vars['row_dates'][$i] = l( $date, '', array('fragment' => $vars['timelinr_dates_id'] . '_' . $i, 'external' => TRUE));
```

which output a result like:
    mydate

I would like now to output something like:

```
<a href="...">
    <h2>mydate</h2>
    <h1>mytitle</h1>
</a>
```

the problem is that if I do:

```
$date = "<h2>mydate</h2>";
$title = "<h1>mytitle</h1>"
```

then the markups are outputed like text
Is there a way to acheive it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the html-Option of l() to true:

```
l( $date, '', array(
  'fragment' => $vars['timelinr_dates_id'] . '_' . $i, 
  'external' => TRUE, 
  'html' => TRUE
));
```

Otherwise all html-tags get escaped by l().

Comment: super! thanx Nebel54 !